# //<node> doesn't give all nodes that matches

Tags: c#, xslt

Given the following XML:

```
<root>
  <StepFusionSet name="SF1">
      <StepFusionSet name="SF2">
      </StepFusionSet>
  </StepFusionSet>
  <StepFusionSet name="SF10">
  </StepFusionSet>
</root>
```

The following C# code :

```
        XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument("input.xml");
        var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();

        var item = nav.Select("//StepFusionSet[@name]");
        while (item.MoveNext())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Current.GetAttribute("name", item.Current.NamespaceURI));
        }
```

Gives me the output :

```
SF1
SF2
SF10
```

But the following XSLT file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="//StepFusionSet">
    <xsl:call-template name="a"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="a">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@name"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(called by C# code:)

```
        XslTransform xslt = new XslTransform();
        xslt.Load("transform.xslt");
        XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument("input.xml");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        xslt.Transform(doc, null, ms);
```

Gives me the output :

```
SF1
SF10
```

What I'm doing wrong in my XSLT file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider your first template…

```
<xsl:template match="//StepFusionSet">
```

…as applied to your `SF1` and (nested) `SF2` elements:

```
<StepFusionSet name="SF1">
  <StepFusionSet name="SF2">
  </StepFusionSet>
</StepFusionSet>
```

The template matches your outer `SF1` element; however, it then needs to be reapplied to the children of the matched element in order to match your inner `SF2`.

This can be achieved by embedding a recursive `<xsl:apply-templates/>` inside your second template definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="//StepFusionSet">
    <xsl:call-template name="a"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="a">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@name"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, you can use an `<xsl:for-each>` element to select all your `<StepFusionSet>` elements (including nested ones such as `SF2`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//StepFusionSet">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is to assume that because the template with match="//StepFusion" matches every StepFusion element, it will therefore be called upon to process every StepFusion element. In fact, it will only process those StepFusion elements that have been selected for processing by an xsl:apply-templates instruction.

I suspect that this kind of confusion often exists where people use match'"//StepFusion" instead of the simpler and clearer match="StepFusion". The match attribute tests whether a given element is eligible for processing by this template rule; it's the apply-templates instruction that decides which elements to submit to this test.